# The "mediator pattern" is "service locator"?

Tags: mediator

Here is the mediator pattern, but Im not sure I understand it well.
It basically means, if many object want to talk to each other, then lets create a mediator and they will talk to that mediator: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator/php/example

[image: mediator]

this kinda reminds me purely a "service locator" which still is a "bag" which has object put into it. And its an anti-pattern. Where is the justice?
EDIT: and to me, it also violates Demeter's law:

lets say I have table models injected:

```
class Test
{
    Model users;
    Model usersPasswords;
.
.
.
    this.users.getAll();
}
```

lets refactor:

```
class ModelsMediator
{
    Model users;
    Model usersPasswords;
    Model userEmails;
}

class Test
{
    ModelDecorator models;
.
.
.
    this.models.users.getAll();
}
```

there will be too many . . . dots.